How to send signed document to signers
I use the Docusign Java Rest API to create an envelope with one or more documents.
I don't find the way to send the signed PDF to the signer(s) when the signature process is finished.
Only the account owner get an email with the documents.
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "[Binary content]",
            "documentId": "101",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "document.pdf",
            "signerMustAcknowledge": "view_accept"
        }
    ],
    "emailSubject": "Sign the documents",
    "externalEnvelopeId": "fa0c5d8d-e47c-4d8c-b51f-dd2bfbde3a8e",
    "messageLock": "true",
    "notification": {
        "expirations": {
            "expireAfter": "14",
            "expireEnabled": "true",
            "expireWarn": "2"
        },
        "useAccountDefaults": "true"
    },
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "clientUserId": "signer-0001",
                "deliveryMethod": "email",
                "email": "signer@email",
                "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
                "name": "signer",
                "phoneNumber": {
                    "countryCode": "33",
                    "number": "XXXXXX"
                },
                "recipientId": "a2fc6bfe-4171-4a92-aa00-7e5daa5ac67a",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                    {
                        "signatureProviderName": "UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP",
                        "signatureProviderOptions": {
                            "sms": "XXXXXXXX"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "xposition": "80",
                            "yposition": "620",
                            "documentId": "101",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "recipientId": "a2fc6bfe-4171-4a92-aa00-7e5daa5ac67a",
                            "xPosition": "80",
                            "yPosition": "620"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}

Should I use the Carbon Copy parameter or is there another option ? In my opinion, Carbon copy would be for additional people.

The signers will automatically receive a copy of the document(s) when the envelope "completes" (when all signers and other recipients have completed their actions).
To be most precise, the signers receive a link that enables them to view/download the signed documents.
Is that not happening with your testing?

No, signers don't receive any email. Only the account owner receive one. Is there any problem in the enveloppe I send ?

I've found. As I use embeded signing, I need to check an option in administration panel to allow email to embeded signers.
